# Where are instruction set stored in computer?

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture, instruction-set

it been a while where i took my architecture class Memory part

my question is

where are instructions set stored in computer ?

Comment: "Instruction sets" are a specification, not an actual thing. Do you mean the actual compiled machine code, or how the CPU executes the instructions?

Comment: is instruction set different from instruction set architecture?

and i meant by my question instruction set like [ multiply instruction , add ...etc ]

Comment: There's the instruction set - the idea that some sequence of bits does some action when executed; the hardware on the CPU that implements those actions; and the compiled sequence of those instructions for a particular program. Which are you asking about?

Comment: The decoding process is hard-wired into the CPU's logic gates (or in older CPUs, in a microcode ROM), and that's what defines how a CPU interprets memory bytes as instructions.  See [Modern Microprocessors
A 90-Minute Guide!](http://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/) kind of assumes you already understand that, but it's still very good and understanding the stuff it covers might help you understand how instruction decoding / execution fits into the big picture.